# Is there a way to combine selected attributes into a particular property in a returned Laravel model?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

Is it possible to combine certain fields into a single property once fetched via Eloquent (similar to how the relationships do it) after using a `select` or `addSelect` clause?

I have 3 models, say model **A**, **B** and **C**. I'm writing a RESTFUL API to retrieve a filtered collection of model **A**. Model **A** and **B** have a one-to-one relationship (**A** belonging to **B**), and model **B** and **C** also have a one-to-one relationship (**B** belongs to **C**).

Here is what I've achieved so far:

```
$builder->select(A.*);

...

if (array_key_exists('with_C', $options) || array_key_exists('C_name', $options)) {
    $builder->join('B', 'A.B_id', '=', 'B.id');
    $builder->join('C', 'B.C_id', '=', 'C.id');

    if (array_key_exists('C_name', $options)) {
        $terms = explode(' ', $options['C_name']);

        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            $builder->where('C.C_name', 'like', "%$term%");
        }
    }

    if (array_key_exists('with_C', $options) && $options['with_C']) {
        $builder->addSelect('C.*');
    }
}
```

It seems to retrieve all the information I want, but when I dump out all the data after the final `->get()`, all the `C.*` attributes are just dumped (and some override the `A.*` attributes, such as ID) in the attributes property.

**Is there any possible way to have the C.* attributes grouped into a C property in the retrieved model - similar to how Eloquent relationships do it?**

Answer (score 2):

Occasionally, when casting models, you can add attributes that do not have a corresponding column in your database. To do so, first define an accessor for the value:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the administrator flag for the user.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getIsAdminAttribute()
    {
        return $this->attributes['admin'] == 'yes';
    }
}
```

After creating the accessor, add the attribute name to the appends property on the model. Note that attribute names are typically referenced in "snake case", even though the accessor is defined using "camel case":

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $appends = ['is_admin'];
}
```

Once the attribute has been added to the `appends` list, it will be included in both the model's array and JSON representations. Attributes in the `appends` array will also respect the visible and hidden settings configured on the model.

You can have manipulated relational data accordingly.

Hope this helps.